# percentage function calculating abnormal value

Tags: c++

In the following function I'm receiving abnormal values.

(Please disconsider hungarian notations, I'm following rules of an old source)

```
int nMaxHP = m_pDefender->GetMaxHitPoint();
u_long nPercentHP = 0;
if( nMaxHP > 0 )
    nPercentHP = (  nHP * 100 ) / nMaxHP;

CString show;
show.Format( "%u %d %d", nPercentHP, nMaxHP, nHP );
pUserAttacker->AddTextD3D( show, 0xffff0000 );
```

This is part of a damage code on a game client, `m_pDefender` is the big lion pillar, `nHP` is the hitpoints he has after taking damage and `nMaxHP` is self-explanatory.
`AddTextD3D( CString format, DWORD color )` shows a message as you can see on the image.
[image: Screenshot]

The thing is,
34.000.000 = nMaxHP
33.999.999 = nHP

33.999.999 * 100 = 3.399.999.900
3.399.999.900 / 34.000.000 = 99 (or 99.99999705882353 on double precision)

The question is why `nPercentHP` is 4294967270?

Comment: Well, if `nHP` is a signed, 32-bit variable, you've just overflowed by having an intermediate result of over three billion, causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: so the error is here `nHP * 100`, correct?

Comment: @ViniyoShouta, Yes, convert one operand to an unsigned type first.

Comment: Thank you, had so much thoughts running I couldn't see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your computation is exceeding the 32-bit arithmetic maximum value.

Convert first everything to double